# How a cloud knows how to scale a particular application?

Tags: cloud, scalability

It is known that clouds provide great scalability. The question is - how a cloud can scale my web application without knowing it's architechture?

For example, i have a database that is accessed 20000 times a second. The data is stored on a hard drive, which cannot handle so many requests. If I was storing the data in a cluster, i'd keep parts of the table on different servers (or replicate data on many servers), so each hard drive wouldn't recieve so many requests. How a cloud would solve such problem?

Answer (score 0):

The answer is actually very simple: the "cloud" doesn't know how to do that.
This is something you must have designed into your application from the start.

Answer (score 0):

On an IaaS I guess it is something you should take care of. However, on a PaaS you can automatically scale up/down depending on some parameters like the number of requests you are getting. This [doc](http://wiki.cloudbees.com/bin/view/RUN/Autoscaling+explained) explains how it works on a specific PaaS.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a public cloud like AWS or on-premise solution like Eucalyptus, you will have cloud resource monitoring options called [CloudWatch](http://aws.amazon.com/cloudwatch/). With CloudWatch you can define your preferred number of [disk I/O](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/DeveloperGuide/ebs-metricscollected.html) and [Load Balancing](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/DeveloperGuide/elb-metricscollected.html) metrics.

Additionally, you could add [Cloud Alarms](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/DeveloperGuide/ConsoleAlarms.html) to trigger certain scaling events based on those metrics to ensure high availability of your application.